# Laravel problemas con recuperar el borrado logico

Tags: laravel, error404

En la ruta tengo

```
Route::resource('states', StateController::class);
Route::put('states/{state}', [StateController::class, 'restore'])->name('states.restore');
```

en la vista

```
<form action="{{ route('states.restore', $state)}}" method="post">
  @csrf
  @method('put')                 
</form>
```

controlador

```
public function restore(State $state){
        return($state);
    }
```

pero me sale error 404

Comment: Posiblemente la uri de esa ruta se esté pisando con la ruta update de `Route::resource('states'...`

Comment: Además, cuando usas model binding, laravel va a devolver un 404 si el modelo fue eliminado. Te sugiero que recibas solo el id en el controlador y hagas la consulta manualmente

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono su guia

Answer (score 2):

Tenés varias cosas para corregir:

1. Cuando usás [`Route::resource()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers), las rutas adicionales que quieras agregar se tienen que definir [antes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers), no después.
2. Al definir [`Route::resource('states', StateController::class);`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller) ya se está creando la ruta `states/{state}` mediante `PUT/PATCH` que es la encargada de "actualizar" un modelo. Con lo cual, deberías crear una distinta (salvo que la anterior no la quieras utilizar, pero por las dudas).
3. No hace falta que recibas solo el ID y hagas la consulta de manera manual en cada método del controlador. Lo que te conviene hacer es resolver la consulta desde el [`RouteServiceProvider`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic). De esa manera, lo definís una sola vez y además no haría falta replicar la lógica si llegaras a necesitar pasar un `state` a otro controlador.

---

**web.php**
Cambié el orden y le agregué `/restore` a la URL.

```php
Route::put('states/{state}/restore', [StateController::class, 'restore'])->name('states.restore');
Route::resource('states', StateController::class);
```

**RouteServiceProvider.php**
Definí la lógica para tener en cuenta los modelos "borrados". Asumo que estás usando [soft delete](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#soft-deleting) y que el modelo se llama `State`.

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('state', function ($id) {
        return State::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
    });
}
```